# Is there any way to load just user selected contact groups in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook) loads all contacts from all contact groups.

ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(addressBook, defaultSourceRef) loads contacts from just the default address book.

Is there any way to just load contacts from user selected groups in the contacts groups?

Answer (score 0):

Using ABAddressbook, you can access all contacts in your app, Now, It's depends on you, Which contacts you want to show to user. If you want to show any selected contacts, You have to get selected contacts from your app only, After that you can exclude other contact from main contact list which you want to display.

Finally, It's possible to view selected contacts, But You've to select those contacts from you app only, And it's depends on your logic.

Regards,